# How to convert docx and doc (ioBytes) to pdf (ioBytes) with python

Tags: python, pdf, docx, doc

I have to read the docx or doc document from cloud storage, so I read it as ioBytes, have to convert it to pdf and save it back to storage. I already tried several docx and doc conversion libraries but when I pass ioBytes to these libraries they don't work.

I'm using python 3.8.13.

```
import io
from docx import Document
from docx2pdf import convert

in_file = io.BytesIO(open('prueba.docx', 'rb').read())
    
document = Document()
document.save(in_file)
in_file.seek(0)

output = io.BytesIO()
convert(document, output)
```

After this last step I upload it to the cloud with a .pdf extension

Comment: Please share your code in order to allow someone to help you

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard This is what I have tried

Comment: According to the example https://github.com/AlJohri/docx2pdf#library `convert()` parameters are the names of the files

Comment: Ok, but then how do I convert it from ioBytes?

Comment: @KJ but how do you convert it?